# How to save each line of a np.matrix to a 9 pair touple array?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matrix, networkx

Well I'm trying to create a `matplotlib` animation for a graph using `networkx`, but I got stuck while trying to read a matrix that contains a sequence of nodes, which represents the path to follow, and at the end of each line it has the total weight of that path. So it looks something like this:

```
[node1, node2, node3, ..., node9, weight1   ]
[node1, node3, node2, ..., node9, weight2   ](the nodes 1 to 9 are permuted and 
.                             .     .          then drawed in pairs)
.                             .     .
.                             .     .
[node9, node8, node4, ..., node1, weight(9!)]
```

I'm very new to Python and I'm used to work in C, so what I am trying to do is more like:

1. Check the first line in the matrix, read the nodes and save it in a tuples array:

   `nPath=[(node1,node2),(node2,node3),(node3,node4),...,(node8,node9),(node9,node1)]`
2. Use the weight of that line and test if its the shortest one.
3. Show the path in the graph, then go back and try now with line 2.
4. Repeat.

This is my code so far:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools as it
import matplotlib.animation as animation

#Contains the combinations of each pair of nodes and their weight.
with open("pair_weight.txt","r") as file:
    W_edges = np.loadtxt(file, dtype=int, delimiter='   ')

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(W_edges)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))

#Contains the total waight of each path 1 to 9.
with open("Path_Weights.txt","r") as file:
    W_paths = np.loadtxt(file, dtype=int)

#contains all 9! permutations of the nodes
with open("Permutations.txt","r") as file:
    nPath = np.loadtxt(file, dtype=int, delimiter=' ')

nPaths = np.c_[nPath, W_paths]

pos = nx.kamada_kawai_layout(G)

labels = {}    
for node in G.nodes():
    if node in pos: 
        labels[node] = node

npaths = []

def update_path(num):
    for i in range(0,8):
        if i==8:          #This is were i'm trying to do it like in c.
            npaths.append[(nPaths.item((num, i))),(nPaths.item((num,0)))]
    npaths.append[(nPaths.item((num, i))),(nPaths.item((num,i+1)))]
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=2, edgelist=npaths, edge_color='r')


    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, node_size=900, node_color='skyblue', node_shape='o', alpha=0.7, edgecolor='deepskyblue') 
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, labels, font_size=14, font_color='k', alpha=5)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, edge_color='gray')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_path, frames=6, interval=1000, repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If `nPath` (without the `s`) is your matrix with node paths, let's say with shape `(P, N)` (`P` paths of `N` nodes), you can make an array, say `nPathEdges`, with shape `(P, N, 2)` where `nPathEdges[i, j]` contains the `j`-th edge (represented as `[node1, node2]`) of the `i`-th path, like this:

```
nPathEdges = np.stack([nPath, np.roll(nPath, -1, axis=1)], axis=2)
```

Then you can iterate this matrix and the weights like:

```
w_min = np.inf
for edges, w in zip(nPathEdges, W_paths):
    # You can have it as a list of tuples like this,
    # although as far as I can tell NetworkX should work fine with a NumPy array too
    edges = [tuple(e) for e in edges]
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=2, edgelist=npaths, edge_color='r')
    if w < w_min:
        w_min = w
        # Do something for minimum weight...
```

Comment: Thank you! it does what I needed, but i have a small issue when I try to animate it, i need to animate each line at the time with update_path(num), for my understanding that num will be iterating to animate and if I set frames=1 then num will be iterating over 1, am I correct? and also how do I access only the first line each time num is called?

Comment: @Jorge Ah right, if you want to pick the `num`-th path then instead of the `for` loop you would have `edges = nPathEdges[num]` and `w = W_paths[num]`.